# Calculate relative 3D position from points in stereo images?

Tags: ros, stereo-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody,

I have a (DIY) stereo camera readily calibrated so that it can be used with `stereo_image_proc` which successfully and beautifully creates a point cloud. That's nice so far... but it's not the question.

In addition to the image data (RGB) I also have several key points in image coordinates (x, y) that are generated from the pictures of both, the left and the right eye of the stereo camera. I would like to match these points so that I can calculate the Z-component for each point. That is, I have x1, y1, x2, y2 for each corresponding point and I'd like to have a full blown relative (and later on through `tf` absolute) x, y, z position for each point.

How would I go on about this? There's supposedly some equation that can make this calculation.

Thanks a lot!

//edit: oh, just to add to it: It is known which key point in the left corresponds to which one in the right image. That is, there is no feature matching necessary.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271740/calculate-relative-3d-position-from-points-in-stereo-images?/) by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1145 on 2017-09-28

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-28**:
I'm slightly confused: you mention you already have pointclouds, so that implies that dense-stereo matching / processing is already working and disparity can be (successfully?) calculated. Are you now asking to do the same thing again, but for some specific features in both images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You've got all the information from the stereo calibration to construct an `image_geometry::StereoCameraModel`. You could use the `projectDisparityTo3d` function from the `StereoCameraModel` to get the 3D coordinates. Your input is a pixel location in rectified image `(u, v)` and the corresponding disparity `(x2 - x1)`.

---

Originally posted by [Ronald](https://answers.ros.org/users/20340/ronald/) with karma: 103 on 2017-09-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on 2017-10-05**:
Works like a charm. Thanks a lot!